# htaccess redirect to index.html in same (unknown) subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I like to redirect all request to index.html where the .htaccess is placed

Place of .htaccess:

```
https://example.com/unknown/whatever/.htaccess
```

This request:

```
https://example.com/unknown/whatever/article1
```

should redirect to

```
https://example.com/unknown/whatever/index.html
```

It only works for me, when i know the subfolder path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule . /unknown/whatever/index.html [L]
```

Any idea how to make this work when the subfolder path and count is unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me (requested URL - unknown/whatever/article1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1/index.html [L]
```

server files structure:

```
unknown/whatever/article1/index.html
.htaccess
```

and this one works for me too (requested URL - unknown/whatever/article1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ $1/index.html [L]
```

server files structure:

```
unknown/whatever/index.html
.htaccess
```

request: `unknown/whatever/article1`

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.html
```

Files structure:

```
unknown/whatever/index.html
unknown/whatever/.htaccess
```

Comment: This rule seems to work in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be, but on the server it shows me the files in (existing) folder `https://example.com/unknown/whatever/article1`

Comment: is it redirect `https://example.com/unknown/whatever/article1` to `https://example.com/unknown/whatever/index.html`?

Comment: No, it just shows the folder 'https://example.com/unknown/whatever/article1'. Btw, my live example has much more subfolders if that matters...

Comment: Any other idea? It never redirects. Perhaps because "DirectorySlash Off" is not supported by the tool. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it works if i put the .htaccess in the root folder, but not if it is in https://example.com/unknown/whatever/.htaccess I have to put it there because the rules should only be set for that folder